# Jquery click event capture ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some checkboxes on the screen, they have in their structure, name, class and dynamic id.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="item_addon_1" name="sub_item[487][]" id="addon-4875496"> Product 1 
<input type="checkbox" class="item_addon_2" name="sub_item[488][]" id="addon-4875495"> Product 2 
<input type="checkbox" class="item_addon_3" name="sub_item[500][]" id="addon-4875499"> Product 3
```

I need to capture the click event, and inside the event get the ID of the clicked object, but using the code below the ID is undefined

```
$( document ).on( "click", "[class*='item_addon']", function() {
    
        object = $(this);
            
        
        var id=$(this).data("id");  
        console.log("id: ", id);

    
   });
```

**CODE**

```js
$( document ).on( "click", "[class*='item_addon']", function() {
    
        object = $(this);
            
        
        var id=$(this).data("id");  
        console.log("id: ", id);

    
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="item_addon_1" name="sub_item[487][]" id="addon-4875496"> Product 1 
<input type="checkbox" class="item_addon_2" name="sub_item[488][]" id="addon-4875495"> Product 2 
<input type="checkbox" class="item_addon_3" name="sub_item[500][]" id="addon-4875499"> Product 3
```

Comment: It's not a data attribute. Just use `.id`, no need to even wrap it in a jQuery object first either

Comment: Lack of attention from me. I just changed that $(this).data("id"); for $(this).attr('id');